# AngularJS - How does transformRequest array work? (not the transformRequest function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the use of passing an array of functions to `transformRequest`? Why does it even accept an array when all it needs is just a function?

I understand how `transformRequest` function transforms the data before sending the data to server. I'm looking for a detailed explanation on

- why is the `transformRequest` **Array** important?
- Is it only the 0th index function applied over the data?
- Or all the functions are applied on the data? If so, in which order?

If a transform function is defined globally,

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function () { /* code... */ }];
```

Which is the recommended/best way to override this global function only for few requests?

I have referred to AngularJS docs and on Stack Overflow, but I could not find an answer to this specific question.

Comment: It's a chain of transformers, one feeding in to the next in array order

Comment: And how do we override a function in this array?

Comment: The example in the docs is pretty clear ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request

Comment: But I observed that in my project that using `transformRequest` doesn't override `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest`. I'm using [this transformer in defaults](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: The default `transformRequest` function is not being called but, the data is being stringified as a result, the output is [object Object]. This doesn't happen if I disable the defaults.